# Probability of a combination not happening

Tags: probability, combinations

Billy and Frank are assigned random seats out of 6 seats in a round table what is the chance they aren’t together?

I'm new to prob and stats so any help in regards to explaining the math is greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The probability that they aren't together is $1$ minus the probability that they *are* together.

Comment: This is more complicated than actually calculating the probability that they aren't together.

Comment: @Ennar Hmm, I thought it was more conceptually simple, but you may be right.

Comment: Actually, when I think about it more, it depends on what approach you are using. Both can be done easy or hard way.

Comment: @Ennar actually it's just asking for the probability of them not siting together. I feel like I worded it awkwardly. So... would it be 3/5?

Comment: @fred556, I understand the question. Lovsovs and I are just considering different ways to arrive at the answer.

Comment: @Ennar Right. I will leave my answer as a hint for now though, as OP have not provided any attempt of his own.

Comment: @Lovsovs With regards to your hint. 1 - 2/5 = 3/5

Comment: @fred556 Yep, you got it! :)

Comment: @Lovsovs Could you help me with one more? Or would you like me to make a new post?

Comment: @fred556 It is custom to make a new post. However in that one, please do include what you have tried so far and where/why you are stuck. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Once Billy sits (anywhere), how many nonadjacent seats are left for Frank?